# Convert each row of matrix( float) in to a vector

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, emgucv

I have a float[n,128] array. Now I want to convert each row into a separate vector as following:

// The code here is a Pseudo Code

```
int n=48;  
    float[,] arrFloat=new float[n,128];  
    VectorOfFloat v1 = new VectorOfFloat(128);  // Vn equals to number of n

     v1= arrFloat[0];
     v2=arrFloat[1]
      .
      .
      .
      .
      Vn
```

**What is the optimize way?**

---

I could possibly write the code as following, but I think there should be a better way:

```
 List<VectorOfFloat> descriptorVec = new List<VectorOfFloat>();
VectorOfFloat v1 = new VectorOfFloat();  
                    var temp = new float[128];  
                    for (int i = 0; i < descriptors1.GetLength(0); i++)  
                    {  
                        for (int j = 0; j < descriptors1.GetLength(1); j++)  
                        {  
                            temp[j] = descriptors1[0, j];  
                        }  
                        v1.Push(temp);  
                        descriptorVec.Add(v1);  
                    }
```

Comment: what's wrong with a loop? (which you could have easily shown code for...)

Comment: I am wondering if there is another technique [ more concise ] such as Linq, lamda expressions, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Buffer.BlockCopy or ArrayCopy instead of manually assigning each value in for

```
        static float[][] ToVectors(float[,] matrix)
    {

        var array = new float[matrix.GetLength(0)][];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i]=new float[matrix.GetLength(1)];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(matrix, i * matrix.GetLength(1), array[i], 0, matrix.GetLength(1) * sizeof(float));
        }


        return array;

    }
```

Comment: This would make an array with 128 rows and n columns.
What I m looking for is:  

n separate vectors that each vector has 128 elements

Ex) V1={J1,J2,..,J128}  

    V2={M1,M2,..,M128}

Comment: Have you tried it you should get an array that contains n arrays of 128 floats.

Comment: @ user629926: Yes, it did work without any error. but here I get 128 rows and n columns; as my n=4 so it was a matrix of 128X4